# GCP monitoring widgets and MQL language

Tags: google-cloud-platform, widget, monitoring, mql

[image]

I'm trying to figure out a different approach for monitoring. Instead of using `BUILDER` to get metrics in GCP widgets, I want to use MQL language.

The problem is that when I use MQL I have strange values on the right side (bytes?) instead of MB when I use builder.

Also when I group metrics from different pods by namespace_name I see only namespace name. Is there any change to change the legend value?

For example, the widget from the screenshot should show JVM memory usage (max/usage).

Below is my code.

```
fetch k8s_container
| metric 'external.googleapis.com/jvm/memory/max'
| filter
    (resource.namespace_name == 'NAMESPACE'
     && resource.pod_name =~ 'POD_NAME')
| group_by 1m, [value_max_mean: mean(value.max)]
| every 1m
| group_by [resource.namespace_name]
```

```
fetch k8s_container
| metric 'external.googleapis.com/jvm/memory/used'
| filter
    (resource.namespace_name == 'NAMESPACE'
     && resource.pod_name =~ 'POD_NAME')
| group_by 1m, [value_used_mean: mean(value.used)]
| every 1m
| group_by [resource.namespace_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to change units from bytes to megabytes I used

```
| cast_units ('By')
```

I just still do not know if I can change the legend under the X axis for each metric.